# Should I separate the web-service interface from the other parts of the system?

Tags: php, web-services, rest, laravel, laravel-4

I'm developing a system *(o rly?!)*, a regular system. This system maybe considered normal: CRUD's are all over the place. **BUT**, I also need to access his data as a web service. I'm developing both: the system and the web service, using Laravel 4.

I have controllers, of course, for all the CRUDs on the system so an user can be able to put information on the database. Pretty simply stuff...so far!

As I said: I **need** to consume data on a web-service format. I need to make request and record data to the server throught a JSON string and REST verbs. That being said, here comes the question:

**Should I create a whole new project to access the data as a web service and separate it from the original project (cruds) or this is just a stupid idea of mine?**

I think this might help on the security and on the cohesion on both projects.

Any answer is welcome ans thanks in advance! =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are a coder who can easily organise an additional layer into your current app, to create the web-service layer, then do it.

If (like me, and probably most others) you'll just get swamped in a mess of files and folders, and end up changing code which impacts your already existing app - stay well clear! Write a new web-service app!

Separate the concerns, and sleep happy at night that both animals are caged up separately so they can't kill each other.

Although...you are using laravel. So you can actually create separation quite nicely in one app by using packages (were called bundles in L3). You still might run into the risk that you mess up some code of your current app, but if you are strict with yourself, you should be ok.

One question I'd ask yourself is why not just have the app ONLY be a web service, and create clients that meet any needs you want? It does seem odd to have an app being used as a web server and also as a web service. You may run into all sorts of performance problems if you try to do both in the same app.

UPDATE:

For a definitive answer on if you are doing this the right way: I say no, you aren't doing it the right way. Create a web service from your app, and ONLY allow it to be a web service. Then create client apps (web service consumers) to meet any needs you have for displaying the data.

Comment: My main concern is: routes. See, in my older application, I already have a bunch of them. I'm afraid that some of them may become a security breach, if you know what I mean. I think I'm gonna be able to  change one part of the system without messing with the other, but I was wondering if that's was the best way of doing it! That was the real question, though! =D

Comment: i dont understand. When you add new routes for your web service, just prepend with something like site.com/api/...

Comment: In case I opt for package approch, should I give it the access to my database? Case, in that case I'd have to redeclarate all my models, though.

Comment: I don't know what you app looks like. If your models are all nicely de-coupled, then it will be fine to use them with your new web-service package. If they aren't, and you are thinking you need to re-write your models, you will be better off starting a new app

Comment: They are just fine to be used now. But if I choose turn it into a package, I'm going to need to re-write everything (models), right?

Comment: how would anyone but you know that? You can access ANY class from ANYWHERE. The question really is should you? Only you will know that. There are many design considerations. Its generally not a good idea to allow classes to be accessed from everywhere. Thats why we have MVC,  dependency injection and IoC patterns